# Android Studio NDK release/debug defines

Tags: android, android-ndk

How can I specify a define for the debug build only?

How can I specify a define for the release build only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NDEBUG gets defined when it's a Release build, so you can use that.

E.g.

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define RELEASE_BUILD
#else
#define DEBUG_BUILD
#endif
```